# Django-Admin not found despite installing Django

Tags: python, django, terminal

I am a beginner with Django, and when it comes to stuff dealing with installing packages on computers, I get confused very easily.

I've already installed Django, and yet when I try to create a project, the following message appears...

`can't open file 'U:\django-admin': [Errno 2] No such file or directory`

I've seen on other questions asked, that it would require one to have a virtual environment; however, on the tutorials I've been following, it doesn't install an environment.

Comment: How to do you know you have installed Django? Please post the commands you have entered so far.

Comment: Did you do `django-admin startproject projectname`

Answer (score 0):

In order to start a Django project you have to follow below steps:

**Install Python by visiting [Python Official Website](https://python.org)**

**Setup virtual environment and activate it**

`python -m venv venv`

`.\venv\scripts\activate`

Now your command prompt should change to `venv>`

**Install Django**

`venv>pip install django`

Please read the [official document](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/windows/) carefully.

Comment: Everything works until I start using django-admin. Same error as above

Comment: ```django-admin``` is the first command, so I'm not sure what you mean by "everything works". Please confirm you have installed Python, and your virtual environment is up and running. Please update your original post with the answers.

Comment: You can't install Django and use it without a virtual environment.